# Pass PHP value to javascript using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax-request

I have a php code that provides the database values. I need those values in the javascript variable.

Javascript Code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function text() {
        var textVal=$("#busqueda_de_producto").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"index.php",  //here goes your php script file where you want to pass value
            data: textVal,
            success:function(response)
            {
               // JAVSCRIPT VARIABLE = varable from PHP file.
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

PHP FILE CODE:

```
<?php
    $q11 = "select * from sp_documentocompra_detalle where dcd_codigo".$_GET['codigo']; 
    $res11 = mysql_query($q11);
    $row11 = mysql_fetch_array($res11);
?>
```

Comment: In your PHP code, just do `echo json_encode($row11);`

Comment: if you just want to pass variables from one php page to another just use SESSION. you are just getting variable from a script and passing back to index.php what is the use of them in you html/javascript page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your returning data is in the `response` parameter. You have to `echo` your data in PHP to get the results

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON format is convenient

because of its key-value nature.

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert PHP array to JSON.

`echo` the json_encoded variable

you will be able to receive that JSON response data through `$.ajax`

Comment: but the result comming is NULL

Answer (score 1):

JavaScipt/HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function text()
    {
        var textVal=$("#busqueda_de_producto").val();
        $.post('index.php', { codigo:textVal }, function(response) {
            $('#output').html(response.FIELDNAME);
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    }
</script>
<span id="output"></span>
```

PHP:

```
$q11 = "select * from sp_documentocompra_detalle where dcd_codigo='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['codigo'])."'";
$res11 = mysql_query($q11);
$row11 = mysql_fetch_array($res11);

echo json_encode($row11);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You aren't echoing anything in your PHP script.**

Try altering your PHP to this:

```
<?php
        $q11 = "select * from sp_documentocompra_detalle where dcd_codigo".$_GET['codigo']; 
        $res11 = mysql_query($q11);
        $row11 = mysql_fetch_array($res11);

        echo $row11; //This sends the array to the Ajax call. Make sure to only send what you want.
?>
```

Then in your Ajax call you can alert this by writing `alert(response)` in your success handler.

**Tips**

Send your data to the server as a URL serialised string : `request=foo&bar=4`. You can also try JSON if you fancy it.

Don't use `mysql_*` PHP functions as they are being deprecated. Try a [search](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for PHP Data Objects (PDO).

Answer (score 0):

i see lots of things that needs to be corrected

the data in your ajax do it this way `data: {'codigo':textVal},` since you are using $_GET['codigo'], which leads to the second correction, you used `type:"POST"` so you must also access the $_POST variable and not the $_GET variable and lastly the target of your ajax does not display / return anything you either `echo` it or `echo json_encode()` it

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use 
**echo json_encode("YOUR ARRAY/VALUE TO BE USED");**

and then parse JSON in the javascript code as
**obj = JSON.parse(response);**